# Conditional Statement Determined by Previous Page or Firing off a .click without clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, click

I was wondering if this were possible.

I have a very complicated script, that runs on .click.

I want to run the same script without the user clicking as-well - in the instance that the user clicks to a new page with the correct content open - I have done this a thousand times but in this case the normal wont work..

---

so my question is, can you have a conditional statement that will do something (run a function) if the user has come from a specific page?

or

set off the .click function if in the query string say URL.client_id is present..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
// evaluate id
if(URL.client_id) // or whatever you're passing through here
{
    runFunction();
}

$('#element').click(function()
{
    runFunction();
});

function runFunction()
{
   console.log("runFunction called");
}
```

Comment: You'd better trigger the click with $('#element').click(), in case you change the logic behind the click event (adding functions, renaming it, and so on), it will still be consistant.

Comment: This worked very well just one question - if the condition is true and in the URL scope there is client I'd will the code keep executing?

Comment: Only upon page refresh, it's a run-once type script.  That what you mean?